# C # WPF Running app copies in different domains (for separate cookies)

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, appdomain

There is a task: There is a main WPF application that runs several (different number) copies of another WPF application. Each copy contains a component WebBrowser, on which authorization is performed on the website http://n.site/ Each copy must have its own cookie area, since each copy authorizes different accounts. As you know, the WebBrowser component uses the “one cookie space” for all launched components. I read that in order to divide this "space" we need to run copies in different domains.

Question: how to do this?

P.S. the main application and copies use the same external dll, if that matters.

P.S.S I already implemented this in WinForms, and there the space for cookies was different for app copies without changing the domain.

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: Where the legacy `WebBrowser` control is used, the cookie container is the Win32 application process itself. To my best knowledge, the only way to separate cookie-based sessions for the same domain is to run multiple separate processes. Note sure how you solved that for WinForms, but if you did, just use the same approach for WPF, as it uses the same WebBrowser ActiveX control behind the scene.

Comment: @noseratio you are absolutely right. But this behavior of WebBrowser can be changed. Now I will publish the solution here.

Comment: Note though `INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST` only prevents cookie persistence. It doesn't prevent memory-only cookies from being shared across all WebBrowser instances within the same EXE process. So if you start a session in one instance of WebBrowser, it will be available in another one. Try that with Gmail, I'm pretty sure you'd only have to log in once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!
To change this behavior, you need to change the WinINET settings using the InternetSetOption function. To prevent using common cookies by running copies of the same  application, you must change the WinINET settings when you start each copy using the following function.

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool InternetSetOption(int hInternet, int dwOption, ref int option, int dwBufferLength);

public static void SuppressCommonCookieBehaviour()
{
    /* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

            INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR (81):
                  A general purpose option that is used to suppress behaviors on a process-wide basis. 
                  The lpBuffer parameter of the function must be a pointer to a DWORD containing the specific behavior to suppress. 
                  This option cannot be queried with InternetQueryOption. 

            INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST (3):
                  Suppresses the persistence of cookies, even if the server has specified them as persistent.
                  Version:  Requires Internet Explorer 8.0 or later.
    */


    int option = 3; /* INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST */

    bool success = InternetSetOption(0, 81 /* INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR */ , ref option, sizeof(int));

    if (!success)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("InternetSetOption() returns false");
}
```